# IIS use same certificate but for two websites

Tags: iis, certificate

So I have a certificate called `azerwmetricp02.test2.com`, and when I use this certificate for an HTTPS website where the `Host Name` is the same as the certificate URL, then I can access this website.

But now I want to add a second website to my IIS, which also use https, but I can't use the same URL `azerwmetricp02.test2.com`. Is there a way to use this certificate `azerwmetricp02.test2.com` but for two websites? let's say `website1.azerwmetricp02.test2.com` and `website2.azerwmetricp02.test2.com`?

I did try this guide, but it doesn't work, it just says that I have no access to any website: https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-8.htm

Is this even possible or do I need to get a second certificate so I have one per website hosted on the IIS?

Comment: The host name matching for HTTPS requests and server certificate is exact matching in most cases, so with a certificate that only works for `azerwmetricp02.test2.com` you cannot configure two sites `website1.azerwmetricp02.test2.com` and `website2.azerwmetricp02.test2.com`. It is expected that neither of them works. IIS 8 and above allow you to use SNI bindings, so "individual HTTPS sites bind to corresponding server certificates" is very common.

Comment: I just have both websites under the same folder now, so the one website will be `azerwmetricp02.test2.com/website1` and other one `azerwmetricp02.test2.com/website2`

Comment: I run IIS version 10.0.17763.1

Comment: Probably you can learn the terms used by IIS users, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Hosting two web applications under the same HTTPS site (`azerwmetricp02.test2.com/website1` and `azerwmetricp02.test2.com/website2`) is an option if you like it.

Comment: [Is It Possible to Have One SSL Certificate for Multiple Domains?](https://sectigostore.com/page/one-ssl-certificate-for-multiple-domains/)